# Get the json encoded data to ajax success

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, json

I have a php file with encoded json. What I would like to do is to get each data(maxVote and Id) from encoded json

Here is my php file named results.php

```
<?php
    $result = array();     
    array_push($result,array("maxVote"=>300,"id"=>"li_2"),array("maxVote"=>200,"id"=>"li_1"));
    echo json_encode($result);
?>
```

Since I am new to ajax and json,
what are the codes to put on success so that i will get each maxVote's and each id's

```
$.ajax({
    url: "results.php",
    success: function(){
      ...         
    }
});
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: [parseJSON()](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.parseJSON/)

Comment: http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.each/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use:

```
$.ajax({
  dataType: "json",
  url: 'results.php',
  success: function(data){
    var items = [];
    $.each(data, function(key, val) {
      items.push(key + ' : ' + val + '</br>');
    });
    $('body').append(items.join(''));
  }
});
```

or

```
$.getJSON('results.php', function(data) {

  var items = [];

  $.each(data, function(key, val) {
    items.push(key + ' : ' + val + '</br>');
  });

  $('body').append(items.join(''));

});
```

Answer (score 0):

Add the `data` parameter to your `success` function:

```
$.ajax({
    url: "results.php",
    success: function(data){
      $.each(data, function(id, elt) {
          // use data[id].maxVote or elt.maxVote
      }
    }
});
```